# Is there a name for this bilinear form which compares a linear operator with its adjoint?

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let $X$ be a reflexive Hilbert space with inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and let $A:X\to X$. Denote the adjoint of $A$ by $A^\ast$. Define the bilinear form $B:X\times X\to\mathbb R$ by $$ B(u,v)=\langle u,Av\rangle-\langle u,A^\ast v\rangle=\langle u,Av\rangle-\langle Au,v\rangle.$$
I use $B$ in an ad-hoc way to quantify how non-self-adjoint an operator is, with $B\equiv 0$ corresponding to a self-adjoint operator. It is particularly useful for seeing which terms in complicated operator lead to "non-self-adjointness". Informally, I have been calling $B$ the *adjoint commutator*, but I am curious if this bilinear form is used elsewhere and if it already has a commonly used name.

Comment: Not exactly what you're defining here, but what you have here is related to two separate pieces: In general, for any operator $M:X\to X$, we can define an associated bilinear form $(u,v)\mapsto \langle u,Mv\rangle$. You have this with $M=A-A^*$. The *imaginary part* of $A$ is $\frac{1}{2i}(A-A^*)$. The *real part* is $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^*)$, so $A=\text{Re }A+i\text{Im }A$.